# Stackoverflow for pow(x,n) using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

```cpp
class Solution {
    public:
        double myPow(double x, int n) 
        {
            if(n==0)
                return 1;
            return x*myPow(x,n-1);    
        }
};
```

Can anyone tell me why my code is getting `runtime error`?

It is a brute force approach

Comment: I'm only guessing, but your function `myPow` is not protected against negative powers; for instance `myPow(3, -1)` is going to be a very deep recursion as it returns `3 * myPow(3, -2)` and then `3 * (3 * myPow(3, -3))`, etc

Comment: Please provide a [mre] together with all necessary input values.

Comment: @user207421 The question does *not* have any sample data (input values) that generate the runtime error.

Answer (score 1):

This is because if `x=0` output `1` the output should be`0`, because `0^1 , 0^2 , 0^3 , ...... = 0` then you can add this condition `if(x==0) return 0`

```
    double myPow(double x, int n) 
    {
        // If x^0 return 1
        if(n==0)
            return 1;
        // If we need to find of 0^y
        if(x==0)
            return 0
        // For all other cases
        return x*myPow(x,n-1);    
    }
```

> **Note**: This code is not valid with negative numbers.

> Search about `0^0`